# How to preview image before uploading in Extjs 4.2+

Tags: javascript, image, user-interface, extjs

I want to preview an image before it gets processed server side.

I am capturing the image in the following manner:

```
{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    cls: 'reset',
    width: 357,
    fieldLabel: 'Upload Logo',
    name: 'file',
    allowBlank: false,
    emptyText: 'Browse Location...',
    size: 40,
    validateBlank: true,
    vtype: 'fileUpload',
    buttonText: 'Browse',
    listeners: {
        change: {
            fn: me.onFilefieldChange,
            scope: me
        }
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'button',
    handler: function(){
        Message.waitForLoading();
        var form = this.up('logoandcoloring').getForm();
        if (form.isValid()){
            form.submit({
                // and later processing the request
```

I am looking for help for Extjs 4.2+ version.

Comment: [This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) should give you some ideas

Comment: Thanks Zoran..The link you gave was helpful but is was with Javascript..It would be great if something specific to Extjs could work out else javascript is the last resort.

Comment: AFAIK, Ext component for this doesn't exists. Check [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fum) fiddle, it's created using the example from previous link.

Comment: Thanks Zoran..That helped a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the example [clickhere](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-2-2-html-5-multi-file-upload.html)

Comment: Broken link :( That's at StackOverflow people ask to copy paste the code from source, not just post the link